# Boost echo server example and capturing this and shared_from_this() in lambda

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, boost-asio

In boost [async-tcp-echo-server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) example there is a server class which creates a session on a new connection:

```
acceptor.async_accept(socket, [this](boost::system::error_code ec) {
    if (!ec)
        std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
    do_accept();
});
```

`session::start()` function body:

```
void start() { do_read(); }
```

`session::do_read` method is a private member function:

```
void do_read()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
            if (!ec)
                do_write(length);
    });
}
```

Please, correct me if I am wrong.
The session class inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this` so a control block is already created when calling `shared_from_this()` and no undefined behavior will occur. In the `do_read` function `shared_from_this()` function is used to allow `do_write()` method to be called on object which still exists in memory. If `shared_from_this()` wouldn't be used the object could be deleted when reaching end of scope.

Why is `this` captured in lambda expression?
Is `do_write()` method called on `this` or `self`?

In C++14 could I replace:

```
auto self(shared_from_this());
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)),
    [this, self] ...
```

with:

```
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)),
        [this, shared_from_this()] ...
```

?
Or even with that:

```
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)),
    [self = shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
        if (!ec)
            self->do_write(length);
});
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `self` object is captured into the lambda as an ownership token: as long as the lambda lives, the token lives, and the object won't be destroyed.

Capturing `this` is redundant here, but without it one would have to write

```
if (!ec)
    self->do_write(length);
```

instead of

```
if (!ec)
    do_write(length);
```

which is the same as

```
if (!ec)
    this->do_write(length);
```

Thus, `this` is captured mainly for readability.